# Someone please explain to me this piece of code (java)

Tags: java

This is the whole function that works:

```
    public static void downloadPDF(String link) {
    try {
        System.out.println("opening connection");
        URL url = new URL(link);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        File f = new File("Resume.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        System.out.println("reading from resource and writing to file...");
        int length = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// buffer for portion of data from connection
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
        fos.close();
        in.close();
        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Question: Please explain to me the below code. I want to understand it. Line by line what it does. Thank you.

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    System.out.println("reading from resource and writing to file...");
    int length = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// buffer for portion of data from connection
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
```

Thank you! If there are any tips you can provide to approach this better it would be helpful. I tried to use apache pdfbox but wasn't successful in some aspects. I will try it again but for the meantime this interests me.

Comment: What specifically about it do you want to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what exactly you're asking so I'll just explain it in super basic terms

Open an output stream - this is basically a "connection" to a file that allows you to put information in it.

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Computers don't like to read a whole bunch of stuff at once. Instead, most programs will read in portions, kind of like how you technically read one page of a book at a time, not every page all together at once. Here the buffer is 1024 bytes, which means the file is read 1024 bytes long. So if the file is 2048 bytes then we will read from it twice.

```
    int length = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

So here we read in the file into the buffer. This is limited to the buffer size, but if there isn't enough to totally fill it up that's OK. If there's nothing left to read, then `read` would return `-1` and we'd be done reading.

```
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
```

Now we take the stuff we read from the file, which is currently in the `buffer` array, and write it to the output stream. `0, length` means that we write from index `0` to index `length` in the buffer, and that information is sent to the file that we are creating.

```
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
```

Comment: Oh so everytime we go through the while loop fos writes the 1024 byes that are in the buffer. Once buffer doesn't have anything to read then we return -1. So technically the last loop buffer might necessarily not have 1024 bytes but less?

Comment: Yep! Like if the file is only 500 bytes in the first place, then it will just read 500 bytes into the array. That's why read returns a number - so that you know how much of the byte array is actual data

Comment: Misaka thank you very much.